# Having some trouble removing the scroll event listener from the window in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, dom-events

I'm trying to lock and then unlock the windows scroll conditionally inside `useEffect`. It seems like when I go to remove the scroll event listener it's not matching the referenced function `scrollEvent` for removal.

Any help is appreciated.

```
export const Viewer = () => {
  const [view, setView] = useCustom()
  const enterView = Object.entries(view).length > 0

  const [animation, set, stop] = useSpring(() => ({
    slide: [100],
    opacity: [0],
  }))

  const scrollEvent = offsetY => () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetY,
      behavior: "smooth",
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const offsetY = window.pageYOffset

    if (enterView) {
      set({ slide: [0], opacity: [1] })
      window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent(offsetY), true)
      stop()
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent(offsetY), true)
      set({ slide: [100], opacity: [0] })
    }
  }, [enterView])

  return (
    <ViewerComponent
      setView={setView}
      isActive={enterView}
      inAnimation={animation}
      data={view}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that `scrollEvent` is recreated every render so their references won't match. The easiest way would be to move the `scrollEvent` definition outside of the component, so it's not a part of the lifecycle:

```
 const scrollEvent = offsetY => () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetY,
      behavior: "smooth",
    })
  }

export const Viewer = () => {
  // ...
```

Comment: Still not getting the event removed after pulling the function outside the component. Wondering if its because the function is curried. This is a gatsby site which requires me to call window inside the effect.